non-numeric argument to binary operator in a time series in R
I have this time series object
> dftsEtab
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(2, 13) 
Frequency = 13 
 [1] 152 118  80  74  84  92  88  78  66  72  54  50  49  41  22  17  12  15  15   8
[21]   6   8  13  15   6   8

When I run the holtwinters function it bugs out
> HWEtab <- HoltWinters(dftsEtab)
Error in `-.default`(x, trend) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I've used this function before with a very similar time series and no problems
> dfts
Time Series:
Start = c(1, 1) 
End = c(2, 13) 
Frequency = 13 
 [1] 21633 21756 21343 21362 21469 22197 21757 21066 20743 20649 20123 18908 17512
[14] 17249 15672 14709 14648 14642 14296 13931 13539 13481 14180 13399 12221 11861
> HW1 <- HoltWinters(dfts)


dftsEtab has non numeric values. To replicate this problem, use the following numeric vector d
d <- c(152, 118, 80, 74, 84, 92, 88, 78, 66, 72, 54, 50, 49, 41, 22, 
17, 12, 15, 15, 8, 6, 8, 13, 15, 6, 8)

and run the following code:
char_d = ts(as.character(d),c(1,1),c(2,13),frequency = 13)
HoltWinters(char_d)

Output
Error in `-.default`(x, trend) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

If you fix your input vector to be numeric like d above, you shouldn't have an issue.
d_num = ts(d, c(1,1),c(2,13),13)
HoltWinters(d_num)

Output:
Holt-Winters exponential smoothing with trend and additive seasonal component.

Call:
HoltWinters(x = d_num)

Smoothing parameters:
 alpha: 0.9454705
 beta : 0
 gamma: 0.1

Coefficients:
           [,1]
a     1.8889398
b    -5.1274725
s1    3.9396053
s2   -9.3188186
s3   -9.8403320
s4  -10.3013657
s5   -4.2929491
s6   -0.9099720
s7    1.7095990
s8    6.7604531
s9    2.2201980
s10  13.0024964
s11  -0.1168233
s12   1.0576862
s13   6.0137687


Ok thank you, I didn't realize you could store characters in the time series object. I guess it's just another vector
